# Bootstrap 4 scrollpy not working css selector issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a site I want to use a scrollpy with Bootstrap 4 but it is not working, I guess I have trouble with classes and selectors.
When I hover an element the hover works, but when I scroll it doesnt work.

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
 }

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #17a2b8 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

body {
    position: relative; 
}
```

HTML

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-info">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap 4</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar7">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbar7">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Codeply</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

I guess the problem is on the `nav-bar li a` selectors

Comment: Show your HTML code where the links should scroll to.
Anchors (<a>) are required and must point to an element with that id.

Comment: My problem is that when I pass the mouser over a nav item the 
color: #17a2b8 !important;
background-color: #fff !important; works
but when I scroll the scrollpy works but the .active class does not show the 
color: #17a2b8 !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
property

Comment: Please update your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
color: #17a2b8 !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Try this:

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li a.active {
color: #17a2b8 !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```